# Resharpers Go To Declaration to less file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, web-essentials

I use Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials. Project has `.less` files. If i try `Go To Declaration` of class in markup, Resharper open `.css` file not `.less`. [This article](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/2405368-go-to-definition-to-css-classes) says that it is possible, but i can't. Is there the way to do it?

Comment: I can't see where it actually says that it would go to the `.less` file, only the `.css` file. Therefore I don't think there is a way to do this.